# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build when usnig Get.toNamed() inside FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Using `flutter 2.x` and `Get package` version `^4.1.2`.

i have a widget like so:

```dart
class InitializationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future:
            // this is just for testing purposes
            Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4)).then((value) => "done"),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (shouldProceed(snapshot)) {
            Get.toNamed("/login");
          }

          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            // handle error case ...
          }

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  bool shouldProceed(AsyncSnapshot snapshot) =>
      snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done;
}
```

`Get.toNamed("/login");` used inside `FutureBuilder` leads to this error:

> The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState#b510d):
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

- I tried to check the `connectionStatus` (based on a SO answer) but it didn't work.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

`build` method is intended for rendering UI. You logic is not connected to rendering at all, so even without an error it doesn't make sense to put it into `build` method.

It's better to convert this method to `StatefulWidget` and put the logic in `initState`, e.g.:

```dart
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4))
  .then((value) => "done")
  .then((_) => Get.toNamed("/login"));
```

Comment: Actually i don't want to move to another screen from `.then((_) => Get.toNamed("/login"))` that's the reason why i used `FutureBuilder`, so later on, i want to implement a function that checks for several things like the status of user is he logged in or not and based on that i'll redirect to the appropriate screen from the `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: If this function will be doing some rendering based on the value, there won't be an error.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
     your set state 
  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when the `setState()` is called immediately during the screen's initial `build()`. In order to avoid this, you can do a work around by putting the `setState()` within a `Future.delayed`, something like:

```dart
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () => Get.toNamed("/login"));
```